# how to insert a full screen large background image in html,css?

Tags: html, css, object-fit

The full image is not displayed properly, the bottom of the image is missing, how can I display the full image on screen? (dimensions: 5904 * 4000 px)

I tried with object fit but its not working:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("adult-blur.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: bottom top;
}
```

I also shared a video of this problem in facebook: [here](https://www.facebook.com/sourav.mitra.12979/videos/664711527719822)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take a look at how to include the relevant code in a [minimal, *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see the HTML and other information we need to see the problem. Also, can you include an image instead of a video please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have both:

1. The image show fully
2. Have the image cover the entire background

Remember that the image is of a fixed ratio and most screens will have a different ratio than your image not to mention differences in the actual viewable area (viewport) because of the browser toolbars and OS toolbars.

Your options are:

1. Have the image always be full-width using `width:100%`. This risks having a part of the image cut off at that bottom if it is taller than the viewport or having some white-space at the bottom if the image is shorter than the viewport.
2. Have the image always be full-height using `height: 100%`. This risks having a part of the image cut off at the right side if it wider than the viewport or some whitespace if it  is not as wide as the viewport.
3. Use `backgorund-repeat` to have the image repeated vertically or horizontally to cover any whitespace.

Most other options you can find in CSS do a combination of the above options, with some additions like centering the image where there is white-space.

Most designers select the images with this in mind, choosing images that don't have any important details near the edges, and thus still look good if a small section is cut off at any end.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #body-container {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100vh;
                background: url("j.jpg") center center no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body-container">
            <!-- Place your document contents here -->          
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

Here we used `bootstrap-4`. Put all contents of document body inside `div` container. In styles, `background-size` is used to make our image 100% in width n height. If it image stretches absurdly, you can also try `background-size: cover`.
Finally, `overflow-y` property is used to make our div scrolls vertically